# True or false question. Single variable calculus.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm looking through an old exam and this question popped up:

---

Determine if the assertions below are true or false.

1. If $f$ is differentiable over $(a,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=\infty,$ then it follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$
2. If $f$ is differentiable over $(a,\infty),$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$, then it follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=\infty$
3. If $f$ is two times differentiable over $(a,\infty),$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f''(x)=\infty,$ then it follows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty.$

---

**My attempt:**

1. So if the derivative is constantly increasing, it implies that the slope of the function is constantly increasing. This can only happen if also the function gets bigger and bigger. Also, if a function is differentiable over an interval, then it is also continous.
2. This one is false for because the function can get bigger and bigger, but it's slope remains constant. Take the function $f(x)=2x+1$ for example.
3. If the second derivative is getting bigger and bigger, it means that the slope of the derivative is increasing, but if the slope is increasing, we are back to problem 1 above, so it is true as well.

Any constructive critique?